# Parent to Child interaction in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, interaction

I would like to know how to make a parent-child interaction in Vue.

Let me give you a small example to explain it.

`parent.vue` file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input @input="validate" type="text" />
        <child-component></child-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            validate(event) {
                if (event.target.value == 'hello') {
                    // make my child component to do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

`child.vue` file

```
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            someFunction() {
                alert('Success');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Note**: This is just an example. My actual situation is little complicated to explain here

In this example, I would like to know how to trigger the function `someFunction()` in the child component when the if condition in the parent component becomes true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign a `ref` to your child component and then use `$refs` to call the method on the child component directly.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input @input="validate" type="text" />
        <child-component ref="child"></child-component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            validate(event) {
                if (event.target.value == 'hello') {
                    this.$refs.child.someFunction();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[Vue Docs Ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

Answer (score 5):

you can use [vue event bus](https://medium.com/vuejobs/create-a-global-event-bus-in-vue-js-838a5d9ab03a) to trigger events from different components.

First, initialize `Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();` in your `main.js` file.

let your parent component send events:

```
validate(event) {
    if (event.target.value == 'hello') {
        this.$bus.$emit('throw', 'Hi')
    }
}
```

then let your child component listen:

```
created() {
    this.$bus.$on('throw', ($event) => {
        console.log($event)  //shows 'Hi'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: You can use **props** and **watch/computed** properties for that purpose.

**Parent Component:**

As per your case, you can define `foo` as your `data` property in parent-component and bind `foo` to input element using `v-model` (*the recommended way*) 
**OR** 
keep it the same as you have already done (*listening to the input event*) and once, it is equal to some value ***hello*** (in your case) it changes the `foo` to true.

As soon as `foo` value changes, Vue reactivity comes into play and, it informs/re-renders the child component.

**Child Component:**

Now, here, you can **watch** for changes in the prop and once it turns `true` you can call a function/method (`someFunction`).

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WaleedAli070/eywraw8t/447359/) for your understanding